# Como colocar um texView dentro de um Circulo

Tags: android, android-layout

Senhores eu gostaria de deixar mais rico um textView deixando-o dentro de um Circulo, é uma Lista de Produto com o nome do produto e o valor e este que estaria dentro do circulo, tentei fazer um shape e usa-lo como background mais não ficou legal, como podem ver o meu rounded_shape.xml baixo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="2dp">

<solid android:color="@color/amarelo2"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/branco" android:width="2dp"/>
<corners android:radius="2dp"/>
```

e fazendo uso dele

```
 <TextView
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarytext"
    android:id="@+id/tv_valor"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
```

Mais o efeito foi horrivel

Comment: Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, a resposta do Luc foi a que melhor se ajustou ao que eu queria porque o textView dentro de um Layout e este já com o Background na forma de circulo foi exatamente o que eu queria, buscando colocar um background no textView eu não estava encontrando o resultado desejado, pode até ser que com um ajuste obtivesse o que necessitava. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> layout_rounded_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#694CA7"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#694CA7" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Para editar a cor mude a linha: `<solid android:color=".."` e também não se esqueça da borda ou, se preferir, você pode removê-la.

Depois de ter criado a `drawable` aplique como background de um `container`:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_valor"
            android:text="LC"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Crie um shape circular:

circular_textview.xml

```
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />    
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Declare o TextView desta forma

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="texto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"/>
```

Para que o circulo se ajuste às dimensões do texto inclua este código no `onCreate()`:

```
final View circularTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
circularTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new

     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         @Override
         public void onGlobalLayout() {

            //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                circularTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                circularTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

             //Coloca a largura igual à altura
             int tvWidth = circularTextView.getWidth();
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams tvLayout = circularTextView.getLayoutParams();
             tvLayout.height = tvLayout.width = tvWidth;
             circularTextView.setLayoutParams(tvLayout);
         }
     });
```